# Animate size of UITextField when pressed

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, core-animation

I have a text field that I want to change the width and image of when I touch inside it. The image changes without any issues but the width remains the same. The issue somehow lies in the action triggered when touching the text field because when I create a simple button the animation works. So my question is how to get the animation working when touching the text field.

The animation doesn't work here:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{

                         self.textFieldSearchStore.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"text-field-small.png"];
                         self.textFieldSearchStore.frame = CGRectMake(textFieldSearchStore.frame.origin.x, textFieldSearchStore.frame.origin.y, 248.0f, textFieldSearchStore.frame.size.height);

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){}
     ];

}
```

The animation works here:

```
- (IBAction)test:(id)sender {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{

                         self.textFieldSearchStore.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"text-field-small.png"];
                         self.textFieldSearchStore.frame = CGRectMake(textFieldSearchStore.frame.origin.x, textFieldSearchStore.frame.origin.y, 248.0f, textFieldSearchStore.frame.size.height);

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){}
     ];

}
```

Comment: does the answer below help at all??

Comment: I'm afraid not. The animation works everywhere but in textFieldDidBeginEditing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The issue was that I was using a Table View Controller. Changed to a regular View Controller and now it's working!

Answer (score 0):

Are you touching the frame of self.textFieldSearchStore in any other method like

```
– textFieldShouldBeginEditing:
– textFieldDidBeginEditing:
– textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:
```

or methods that listen to the following notifications:

```
UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
```

or any of these methods

```
– canBecomeFirstResponder
– becomeFirstResponder
– touchesBegan:withEvent:
```

If so I would set a breakpoint on these methods to see if they are being called after the method above. Let me know if it's helpful.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the textFieldDidBeginEditing method as I have shown in my code snippet. But thats the only method that I use for touching the frame.